# How to install the packages by passing EC2 user data at the launch time using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I want to install nginx by passing it as the user data to the ec2 instance at the launch time. I am passing it like this

```
- name: WebServer | Create the WebServer Instance(s)
  local_action:
    module: ec2
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    group: "{{ ec2_security_groups[1].sg_name }}"
    keypair: "{{ key_name }}"
    instance_type: "{{ web_instance_type }}"
    ****user_data: "sudo apt-get install nginx -y"****
    image: "{{ imgae_id.ami }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ public_subnet }}"
    assign_public_ip: True
    wait: True
    wait_timeout: 600
```

But the above method didn't work for me although it has created the EC2 instance successfully but didn't install the nginx.

Can you please point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the shebang, try the following:

```
- name: WebServer | Create the WebServer Instance(s)
  local_action:
    module: ec2
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    group: "{{ ec2_security_groups[1].sg_name }}"
    keypair: "{{ key_name }}"
    instance_type: "{{ web_instance_type }}"
    user_data: |
               #!/bin/sh
               sudo apt-get install nginx -y
    image: "{{ imgae_id.ami }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ public_subnet }}"
    assign_public_ip: True
    wait: True
    wait_timeout: 600
```